# R 3.6.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS - Accessing indexes out of defined length of a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector in R, say `x` containing elements 1 to 20.

```
> x <- c(1:20)
```

Why is the output of the following commands different when, in both cases, the index to the vector is out of the defined range?

```
> x[0]
integer(0)

> x[5000]
[1] NA
```

I am using a machine with the following configuration.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic


R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
```

Comment: `x[0]` doesn't exist, R indexing is 1-based, `x[5000]` *does exist*, it's value is just not defined yet, hence `NA`.

Comment: integer(0) means R is not even going to check as nothing matches to what you ask. If you are going to ask something logical (i.e.) a value greater than 1, then it will have a look and then reply to you as found (i.e.) the value (if the value inputted is between 1 to 20 as per the current example) or if inputted value is greater than 20, it will just shout back NA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R is 1 indexed.

Indexing with 0 means 'do not select anything'.

Hence you get back a result which tells you it is an integer array of size 0

You may think this is useless, but it makes more sense when used in linear indexing contexts:

```
> x <- 1:10
> r <- as.integer( runif( 10, min = 0, max = 10 ) )
> r
[1] 8 6 7 6 3 0 9 0 8 6
> x[r]
[1] 8 6 7 6 3 9 8 6
```

The result is of length 8, because the 0 indexing operations have been ignored.

Regarding NA,  consider this:

```
> y <- 1
> y[5] <- 5
> y
[1]  1 NA NA NA  5
```

In other words, if you do not explicitly define elements, they are assumed to be NA (i.e. 'undefined'). But you can still access them, and even assign to previously undefined indices.

Similarly, if you use NA as part of linear indexing, you will get NA back, which makes sense if your list of indices was generated from some other process, and you were missing some data in that list.

```
> x <- 1:10
> x[ c(1, 2, NA, 3, 4, NA, 5, 6) ]
[1]  1  2 NA  3  4 NA  5  6
```

One odd behaviour is that, if you try to index with NA by itself, you get an array full of NAs. E.g. check this out:

```
> Robin <- 1:8
> cat( Robin[NA], 'Batman', sep="\n" )
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
Batman
```