# Unexpected return for NA in factor lookup

Tags: r, subset, na, r-factor

I have a factor that I'm using as a lookup table.

```
condLookup = c(hotdog = "ketchup", ham = "mustard", popcorn = "salt", coffee = "cream")
```

This works as expected - I put in a 3-vector and get a 3-vector back:

```
condLookup[c("hotdog", "spinach", NA)]
  hotdog      <NA>      <NA> 
"ketchup"       NA        NA
```

This too is expected, even tho the returns are all `NA`:

```
condLookup[c(NA, "spinach")]
<NA> <NA> 
  NA   NA
```

And this:

```
condLookup["spinach"]
<NA> 
  NA
```

But then this surprised me - I gave an atomic NA, or two NA, and I got a named vector of 4 NA's back.

```
condLookup[NA]
<NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 
  NA   NA   NA   NA 
condLookup[c(NA, NA)]
<NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 
  NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Apparently, for `vector2 <- condLookup[vector1]` then `vector2` will be the same length as `vector1` *unless* every element in `vector1` is NA.  In which case `vector2` is the same length as `condLookup`.
Can you explain this behavior?

Comment: you reminded me [of a recent answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61701997/4183191) :)

Comment: It took me a minute, but I finally got the pun.  :-)

Comment: Related post, where `NA` is used to index `integer` vector, with similar recycling: [Indexing integer vector with NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991967/indexing-with-na)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NA` values are typed, and the type matters: `c(NA,"spinach")` coerces `NA` to character, which isn't recycled:

```
condLookup[NA]
## <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 
##   NA   NA   NA   NA 

condLookup[NA_character_]
## <NA> 
##  NA
```

The default type of `NA` is *logical*.  Logical vectors will get recycled to match the length of the vector, while character vectors will be used to match the names of the vector. From `?[`:

> Character vectors will be matched to the ‘names’ of the object

> ... ‘i’, ‘j’, ‘...’ can be logical
> vectors, indicating elements/slices to select.  Such vectors
> are recycled if necessary to match the corresponding extent.

Comment: this also nicely explains why a[ c( NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA )] will yield 6 NA's, not 4 :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Ben's answer--recycling, `?Extract` displays the following statement:

> - Neither empty ("") nor NA indices match any names, not even empty nor missing names. If any object has no names or appropriate dimnames, they are taken as all "" and so match nothing.